# Get access to wwwroot folder in AWS Elastic Beanstalk .net core application

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

For the last couple days I've been trying to figure out the best way to store images for my EB .net core project. When I initially developed it, I just stored the images in the `wwwroot/images/{whatever I needed}` directories. However, I found shortly after deployment, that the project does not have permission to write (and probably read, no way of knowing yet) that folder.

The specific error message I get is `"Access to the path 'C:\\inetpub\\AspNetCoreWebApps\\app\\wwwroot\\images' is denied`

I've tried integrating AWS's EFS, but I can't seem to figure that out either. I added the `storage-efs-mountfilesystem.config` file that's mentioned in the AWS EB EFS documentation, but to no avail. Not only do I not have access to any folder named `/efs`, I'm not even sure that's the right path.

About the only available option I see is storing all the images as blobs in the DB, which I'd really rather avoid.

I've tried gaining access to the wwwroot folder using this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27393459/4765038), but there doesn't seem to be any change in the response I'm getting.

I'm under contract, and need this up and working sooner, rather than later. If I must, I'll go the db route, but it's hardly a long term option. Although it is a small application, and for the foreseeable future will only have one active user.

The code for the file upload just in case you need it is below:

```
[Route("Image"), HttpPost()]
    public async Task<ResponseInfo> SaveImage()
    {
        try
        {
            var file = Request.Form.Files.FirstOrDefault();
            if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
            {
                if (file.Length > _MaxFileSize)
                {
                    return ResponseInfo.Error($"File too large. Max file size is { _MaxFileSize / (1024 * 1024) }MB");
                }
                var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();
                if (extension == ".png" || extension == ".jpg" || extension == ".jpeg" || extension == ".gif")
                {
                    var filename = String.Concat(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss"), extension);
                    var basePath = Path.Combine(_Env.WebRootPath, "images", "tmp");
                    if (Directory.Exists(basePath) == false)
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(basePath);
                    }
                    using (var inputStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(basePath, filename), FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            await file.CopyToAsync(inputStream);
                            return ResponseInfo.Success(filename);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            ex.Log();
                            return ResponseInfo.Error("Failed to save image");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return ResponseInfo.Error($"File type not accepted. Only PNG, JPG/JPEG, and gif are allowed");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return ResponseInfo.Error(ex.Message);
        }
        return ResponseInfo.Error("No files received.");
    }
```

If it matters, I'm running the latest VS 2017 Community. Publishing to aws using `AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio 2017 V1.14.4.1`.

Comment: Hello! did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Hello! No I did not. I ended up storing my files straight in the db as blobs.

Comment: Hey! A workaround worked for us. :) I will post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be late but this might help others. However, we were not able to access the wwwroot but we made a new directory and made changes to our code to access files from that path.

We have added a folder to our project `.ebextensions` and under that we have added a file `dirAccess.config` (name can be different)

dirAccess.conifg

```
commands:
  0_:
    command: 'if not exist "C:\\inetpub\\assets" mkdir C:\\inetpub\\assets'
  1_:
    command: 'icacls "C:\\inetpub\\assets" /grant "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool:(OI)(CI)F"'
  2_:
    command: 'icacls "C:\\inetpub\\assets"'
```

Please make sure that this folder (`.ebextensions`) is included in the publish zip.

To include the folder in publish, need to add below lines to `.csproj`

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include=".ebextensions\alarms.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include=".ebextensions\assetsDirectory.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```